# Inserting a new element in vector using a braced init-list

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

Given the following struct:

```
struct TestStruct
{
  int mA;
  int mB;
};
```

and the following container:

```
std::vector<TestStruct> _testContainer;
```

The compiler throws an error when attempting to add items using a braced init list as follows:

```
_testContainer.push_back({1,2});
```

I am using visual studio's C++ compiler from 2010 which could be the culprit. Is this valid C++ or am I missing something?

Comment: Try `_testContainer.push_back(TestStruct{1,2});`

Comment: Strange ... works for me in VS2013

Comment: As a sidenote, make sure that you don't declare that variable in the global namespace, because its name is illegal there.

Comment: MSVS is known for having shoddy (or just late) C++ compliance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVS 2010 is not C++11 compliant.  I suggest upgrading to MSVS 2015 and trying again.  As you can see from this example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main(void) {
    std::vector<foo> data;
    data.push_back({1,2});
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fb3a940f60b9824)</kbd>

It is okay.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using visual studio's C++ compiler from 2010 which could be the culprit.

Could well be, VS2010 didn't support the current language standard.

> Is this valid C++ or am I missing something?

[Yes it's valid c++ syntax.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab2d9204015c5c9f)

Answer (score 0):

According the the C++11 standard, this should be okay:

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<foo> data;
    data.push_back({1,2});

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<foo> data;
    data.emplace_back(1,2);

    return 0;
}
```

MSVC still have trouble with newer standard, upgrading to 2013 or even 2015 should help.